# Making payments live in Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I have done testing in my project using sandbox account of Authorize.net. I want to make it live. What is the procedure and changes to my project to accept live payments from customers? What is to be done at Authorize.net side? Do I have to pay or make any account?

Comment: "Do I have to pay or make any account?" - I wasn't aware I could get money from major credit-card networks over the internet completely anonymously...

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net is only a payment gateway. They facilitate payments between a website and a merchant account account/payment processor.

To process payments in your website using Authorize.net you will need to be a registered business physically located in North America (United States and Canada). You also will need a merchant account which can be applied for through Authorize.net although you can get one from any US and Canadian merchant account provider.

Once you have a merchant account linked to your Authorize.net gateway you can use your production Authorize.net account, which is not the same one as your sandbox account, to process payments through your website.